# Object oriented alternative to glob/globfree

Tags: c++, oop, glob

I'm currently using [`glob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Globbing) to match UNIX pathnames against an input string containing wildcards. My dirty code looks like this:

```
glob_t gl;
int result = glob(inputString, GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &gl);
try {
    // do whatever
} catch(...) {
    globfree(&gl);
    throw;
}
globfree(&gl);
```

I wonder if there's a smarter way to do this job in C++. I've been searching for a class that would encapsulate the call to `globfree` in the destructor or something similar but didn't find anything out of the box.

Comment: Write a simple RAII wrapper. It would contain a `glob_t`, take essentially the same arguments in its constructor as `glob`, and call `globfree` in its desctructor.

Answer (score 2):

A smarter, entirely C++-way of doing what you want is using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm.
Especially `directory_iterator` helps you to accomplish what you want.
Please see the excellent [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html) about how to use it!

Comment: Thanks, using boost just for the globbing looks like overkill, but I guess that would do really fine.